# Alternatives to RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

I like the idea of using RelativeLayout as an alternative to many LinearLayouts, but it seems to fall short in a couple of areas.

1. Its behavior for child views that have `visibility=gone` is atrocious.  It seems like the natural behavior for gone views would be to treat them as if they had width and height of 0, but instead it removes them as anchors and any other views that are laid out relative to the gone views get put in unpredictables places.  Yes, it's possible to use "layout_alignWithParentIfMissing" to work around some of these issues, but that's not really the same thing, is it?
2. It doesn't support the `layout_weight` option that I find so useful in LinearLayout.

Are there any good alternatives to RelativeLayout out in the wild that solve these or similar problems?

Comment: I don't know why, but i love linear layouts and don't really love relative layouts. And i'm missing layout_weight as well

Comment: Agreed.  Romain Guy proposed using RelativeLayouts as a way to reduce the size of the view hierarchy in one of his android performance talks, but try as I might I can't find it in my heart to love RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested layouts with Relative Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
     <widget>
     <Widget>
  </LinearLayout>
  <TableLayout
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    <TableRow>
     <Widget>
     <Widget>
    </TableRow>
       <Widget> // By itself in the middle of a table layout
  </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just a very simplistic example.  Any container type can be nested inside of a RelativeLayout, but ScrollView can only have 1 direct child.

Comment: Thanks Phobos.  That's true, although it sort of defeats the purpose of using RelativeLayout to reduce the number of layout objects.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt realize you were trying to reduce the number of overall layout objects.